# Heroku Rails App Can't Find Views For Crawlers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, heroku, twitter, facebook-opengraph

My heroku app responds great to a normal web request: http://feedmevr.herokuapp.com/uploads/10

Unfortunately when using the [Facebook Debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/sharing/?q=http%3A%2F%2Ffeedmevr.herokuapp.com%2Fuploads%2F10) or [Twitter Debugger](https://cards-dev.twitter.com/validator) it returns a 500 error with these logs:

```
2016-06-13T23:30:14.595942+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/uploads/10" host=feedmevr.herokuapp.com request_id=50451e5c-eda1-4225-83f9-cff8c183fd82 fwd="104.7.65.62" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=101ms status=200 bytes=8533
2016-06-13T23:30:29.974017+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/robots.txt" host=feedmevr.herokuapp.com request_id=09617086-d1d1-49d2-9e51-6b6bf4f90917 fwd="199.59.148.209" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=2ms status=200 bytes=154
2016-06-13T23:30:30.141722+00:00 app[web.1]:   Upload Load (2.0ms)  SELECT  "uploads".* FROM "uploads" WHERE "uploads"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 10]]
2016-06-13T23:30:30.117058+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by UploadsController#show as */*
2016-06-13T23:30:30.117070+00:00 app[web.1]:   Parameters: {"id"=>"10"}
2016-06-13T23:30:30.178367+00:00 app[web.1]:
2016-06-13T23:30:30.178376+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionView::MissingTemplate (Missing template uploads/show, application/show with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:all], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :coffee, :arb, :jbuilder]}. Searched in:
2016-06-13T23:30:30.178378+00:00 app[web.1]:   * "/app/app/views"
2016-06-13T23:30:30.178379+00:00 app[web.1]:   * "/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/bundler/gems/activeadmin-3b2015c8948b/app/views"
2016-06-13T23:30:30.056383+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/uploads/10" for 199.59.148.209 at 2016-06-13 23:30:30 +0000
2016-06-13T23:30:30.170305+00:00 app[web.1]:    (1.8ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "zip_files" WHERE "zip_files"."upload_id" = $1  [["upload_id", 10]]
2016-06-13T23:30:30.177291+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 60ms
2016-06-13T23:30:30.178382+00:00 app[web.1]:
2016-06-13T23:30:30.178383+00:00 app[web.1]:
2016-06-13T23:30:30.178382+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/controllers/uploads_controller.rb:15:in `show'
2016-06-13T23:30:30.178380+00:00 app[web.1]:   * "/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/devise-4.1.0/app/views"
2016-06-13T23:30:30.178381+00:00 app[web.1]: ):
2016-06-13T23:30:30.178379+00:00 app[web.1]:   * "/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/kaminari-0.16.3/app/views"
```

The serach for `"/app/app/views"` is particularly strange, as it should be in `"/app/views"` but I don't know what's causing this.

I've tried to fix this all day to no avail. Switching from Puma server to Unicorn server didn't work.

Thanks so much for the help... I'm about to out my head through a wall.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figured it out. The Rails app was throwing an error because I was using `respond_to`. I'm not sure why this was only affecting crawlers.

old code:

```
def show
  respond_to do |format|
    if @upload.downloadable?
      format.all
    else
      flash[:error] = 'The experience you tried to view is invalid'
      format.html { redirect_to :root }
      format.json
    end
  end
end
```

new code:

```
def show
  if request.format != :json && !@upload.downloadable?
    flash[:error] = 'The experience you tried to view is invalid.'
    redirect_to uploads_url
  end
end
```